# Implementation of Point, Velocity and Acceleration in Haskell

Tags: haskell, physics

I'm trying to implement point, velocity and acceleration types.

They should be connected by some `derive` function which:

- takes time and velocity and returns a point increment;
- takes time and acceleration and returns a velocity increment.

In pseudocode, it should look like this:

```
derive :: Time -> Velocity -> Point
derive :: Time -> Acceleration -> Velocity
```

`Time` is a type representing a time as floating value.

`Point`, `Velocity` and `Acceleration` are vectors.

So I don't want to

- mix time values with any other floating values;
- mix vectors representing points with velocity vectors and etc.

I came up with following solution.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import Control.Comonad

import GHC.TypeLits
import Linear
import Linear.V2


-- Type of real numbers.
type R = Double

-- Type of vectors.
type Vector = V2


-- Wrapper to distinguish time values from other values.
newtype Time a = Time { fromTime :: a }

-- Time is intended to be a wrapper. But to implement a derive function,
-- I need a common way to extract value from wrapper. That's why Time
-- must be a Comonad's instance:

instance Functor Time where
    fmap f = Time . f . fromTime

instance Comonad Time where
    extract = fromTime
    duplicate = Time


{- Type of derivative.

     Type (D r v u a) means a derivation of (u a) by (v a) with rank r.

-}
newtype D (r :: Nat) (v :: * -> *) (u :: * -> *) a = D { fromD :: (u a) }


-- Using type D the point, velocity and acceleration types can be defined:
type Pnt = D 0 Time Vector R
type Vel = D 1 Time Vector R
type Acc = D 2 Time Vector R

-- Even if I don't want to mix points with velocities,
-- I do want them to behave like vectors. So I want
-- them to be Additive:

instance Functor u => Functor (D r v u) where
    fmap f = D . fmap f . fromD

instance Additive u => Additive (D r v u) where

    -- I didn't found a way how to make this Additive instance better.
    -- Applicative instance for (D r v u) doesn't help.

    zero = D $ zero

    x ^+^ y = D $ (fromD x) ^+^ (fromD y)
    x ^-^ y = D $ (fromD x) ^-^ (fromD y)

    lerp a x y = D $ lerp a (fromD x) (fromD y)

    liftU2 f x y = D $ liftU2 f (fromD x) (fromD y)
    liftI2 f x y = D $ liftI2 f (fromD x) (fromD y)


-- Now derive function can be implemented:
derive ::
    (Comonad v, Functor u, Num a) =>
        v a -> D (r + 1) v u a -> D r v u a

derive dv du = D $ (extract dv) *^ (fromD du)
```

This solution pretty mush does what I want:

- I can't call `derive` on `Pnt`;
- `derive` on `Vel` returns `Pnt`;
- `derive` on `Acc` returns `Vel`.

I don't like:

- the way how `Additive` instance for `D r v u` is implemented.
- the fact that to derive a vector of real numbes I need to extract time value from a wrapper. It doesn't feel natural.

So ...

- How can I edit an `Additive` instance for `D r v u` to avoid using common code with `fromD`?
- Am I wrong about naturality which I meantioned above; is it ok to use wrappers like `Time` like I did in `derive` function?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes) if you use the same instance as the wrapped type anyway. Together with [`DeriveFunctor`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#deriving-functor-instances), we can get rid of much boilerplate (comments omitted, changes noted with `-- <--`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, DeriveFunctor #-}                -- <--

import Control.Comonad

import GHC.TypeLits
import Linear
import Linear.V2    

type R = Double    
type Vector = V2    

newtype Time a = Time { fromTime :: a } deriving (Functor, Num)           -- <--

instance Comonad Time where
    extract = fromTime
    duplicate = Time

newtype D (r :: Nat) (v :: * -> *) (u :: * -> *) a = D { fromD :: (u a) }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Additive)                             -- <--

type Pnt = D 0 Time Vector R
type Vel = D 1 Time Vector R
type Acc = D 2 Time Vector R

derive ::
    (Comonad v, Functor u, Num a) =>
        v a -> D (r + 1) v u a -> D r v u a

derive dv du = D $ (extract dv) *^ (fromD du)
```

This immediately gets rid of your `Additive` problem. Also, now that `Time` is a `Num` instance, you can use `derive` like this:

```
derive 3 (pure 3 :: Vel)
```

Unfortunately, `Num` also contains `(*)`, so you'll be able to multiply time values, which doesn't really make sense in this case. Alas, there is no other way to get `fromInteger` otherwise.

However, let's have a look at the wrapper, `D` and `derive`. The type of `derive` is a little bit too general. It allows you to do stuff like this:

```
ghci> import Data.Tree
ghci> derive (Node 10 []) (pure 2 :: D 2 Tree Vector Double)
D {fromD = V2 20.0 20.0} -- if we add Show to D's instances
```

Could this be a valid use case? Who knows. Is it *likely* to be a valid use case? Rather not. Get back to the original inspiration for `derive`:

```
derive :: Time -> Velocity     -> Point
derive :: Time -> Acceleration -> Velocity
```

We expect the first argument always to be some kind of time measurement. We also expect the vector to be conform to the time's unit(*). From this point of view, it makes sense to encode the `Time` in `D`. However, this yields the question why the other side of the spacetime, space, isn't encoded in `D` too.

<sup>(*) strictly speaking, we're not encoding time's unit but only type.</sup>

Either way, you probably want to allow only `Time` values. Furthermore, you want to make clear what *unit* `Time` uses. We could use a phantom type, e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GeneralizedNumtypeDeriving #-}
data TimeUnit = Milliseconds | Seconds | Minutes | Hours

newtype Time (* :: TimeUnit) a = Time {fromTime :: a} deriving (Show, Num)
```

which makes sure that we don't mix different times:

```
> (Time 3 :: Time 'Seconds Double) + (Time 10 :: Time 'Minutes Double)
Couldn't match type ‘'Minutes’ with ‘'Seconds’
Expected type: Time 'Seconds Double
  Actual type: Time 'Minutes Double
In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely
  ‘(Time 10 :: Time Minutes Double)’
In the expression:
  (Time 3 :: Time Seconds Double) + (Time 10 :: Time Minutes Double)
```

But that's out of scope for this review. Instead, we can simply say that `Time`'s unit is seconds, disallow creating `Time` values with its data constructor, and provide some helper functions:

```
module Movement 
 ( Time, getSeconds
 , seconds, minutes
 , ...
 )
where

newtype Time a = Time { getSeconds :: a }

seconds :: Num a => a -> Time a
seconds = Time

minutes :: Num a => a -> Time a
minutes = seconds . (60 *)

derive :: (Functor u, Num a) => Time a -> D (r + 1) u a -> D r u a
derive (Time s) du = D $ s *^ (fromD du)
```

Alright. Let's reflect all changes:

- used `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to get rid of boilerplate (major change)
- instead of allowing general `Comonad`s, only allow `Time` (*)
- removed `Time` from `D`, since `derive` fixes it  (*)
- make the unit of time explicit with "smart" constructors and remove the `Time` data constructor from the exports.

<sup>(*) You can still use those techniques internally, but a public interface should be hard to use wrong if possible. After all, that's the reason you're using `r :: Nat` and `derive :: ... -> D (r + 1) ... -> D r`, right?</sup>

We end up with the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, DeriveFunctor #-}
module Movement 
 ( Time, getSeconds
 , R, Vector, 
 , D(..), Pnt, Vel, Acc
 , seconds, minutes
 , derive
 )
where

import GHC.TypeLits
import Linear
import Linear.V2    

type R = Double    
type Vector = V2    

newtype Time a = Time { getSeconds :: a } deriving (Functor)

newtype D (r :: Nat) (u :: * -> *) a = D { fromD :: (u a) }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Additive, Show)

type Pnt = D 0 Vector R
type Vel = D 1 Vector R
type Acc = D 2 Vector R

seconds :: Num a => a -> Time a
seconds = Time

minutes :: Num a => a -> Time a
minutes = seconds . (60 *)

derive :: (Functor u, Num a) => Time a -> D (r + 1) u a -> D r u a
derive (Time s) du = D $ s *^ (fromD du)
```

> Am I wrong about naturality which I meantioned above; is it ok to use wrappers like Time like I did in derive function?

Using wrappers is fine. For example, the [`UniversalTime` in the `time` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:UniversalTime) is just a wrapper around `Rational`. And although it doesn't export its constructor, [`DiffTime`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:DiffTime) is also just a `newtype` of `Pico`.

Maybe it feels more natural with the helper functions:

```
someCalculation :: Vec
someCalculation =
  let time = seconds 120
      acc  = D (V2 10 10) -- (*)
  in derive time acc
```

<sup>(*) This example will probably inspire you to provide `Num a => a -> a -> D r V2 a` functions.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for review! Actually, I tried to make `D` general enough to do not stick to time only. But I didn't mention that in question and I don't see how could I practically use it. I like the way how you modified time. And generalized deriving shorted code pretty well leaving only reasonable parts.